# SQL Query procedure: adding new column based on select query

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

Alright guys so yesterday I asked how to create a extra column in an sql query based on certain conditions and someone told me to use a CASE WHEN statement(Thank You again!) which did work but it only resulted with the fields that where true and excluded everything else, I need all the fields to show and I had to add some more joins to my query and now I cant even tell if it works because its still executing after 2 hours. When I remove the case statement it executes in 6 seconds so I am assuming the problem is with the case statement. Is there any other way to go about adding an new column called 'Eligibilty' to a select query with the values based on:

> If the 'End Use' field is civil AND it exists in the p_SpecialPrograms table its value in the new column would be 'C'.
>
> If it 'END USE' field does not equal to civil then the value in the new column would be just blank

```
Select distinct 
pn.PNumber, 
rp.PDescriptionText, 
ht.HNumber AS 'HTS', 
chs.CHistoryState AS 'HTS State', 
ct.CWhereUsedName AS 'End Use',
--CASE WHEN 'End Use' LIKE 'Civil%' AND pts.PSpecialTradeProgramAdded IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' ELSE 'C' END as 'Eligibility'
from t_COMPClients cc 
  join t_part pt on pt.coclientid=cc.coclientid AND cc.coclientid = 279
  join t_PARTNumbers pn on pn.PID=pt.pid
  join t_PARTDescriptions rp on rp.PID=pt.PID
  join t_PARTDescriptionTypes sp on   sp.PDescriptionTypeID=rp.PDescriptionTypeID AND sp.PDescriptionTypeID=1
  JOIN t_CLASS cs ON pt.PID = cs.PID
  JOIN t_CLASSHistory ch on ch.CID = cs.CID AND (ch.CHistoryStateID = 1 OR ch.CHistoryStateID = 2 OR ch.CHistoryStateID = 3)
  JOIN t_HTS ht on ht.HID = ch.HID AND ht.SYSubprocessID=8
  JOIN t_SYSSubProcesses sb on ht.SYSubprocessID = sb.SYSubProcessID
  JOIN t_CLASSHistoryStates chs ON chs.CHistoryStateID=ch.CHistoryStateID
  JOIN t_CLASSBufferCommodity cb on cb.SYSubProcessID=ht.SYSubprocessID 
  JOIN t_COMPClientSubProcessLink cw ON cw.SYSubProcessID=sb.SYSubProcessID
  JOIN t_CLASSWhereUsedTypes ct ON ct.COClientSubProcessLinkID=cw.COClientSubProcessLinkID
  left join t_PARTSources ps on ps.PID=pt.PID
  left join P_PARTSpecialTradePrograms pts on pts.PSourceID=ps.PSourceID
```

Comment: `'End Use'` will never be `LIKE 'Civil%'`.  You're comparing the literal string "End Use," not the field you constructed.  You will need to do `CASE WHEN ct.CWhereUsedName LIKE 'Civil%'`.

Comment: Those are separated question. Maybe you can ask `why is this query so slow?` In that case we will ask you to check index and provide analyze result. The other question why i dont get the result, you should provide some sample data and desire result. And please read [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Siyual thank you for your response I made the change but its still executing

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I apologize I dont know what you mean by index? The end result just has to have that extra column in the end with the values C or just Blank based on those 2 conditions

Comment: Then you should read [**THIS**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html) Index help db to make query much faster. You use `CREATE INDEX` [**command**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to use an alias inside the same query level.

For example this is invalid, because on the second field `'three'` doesnt exist at this level

```
 SELECT 1 + 2  as 'three', 'three' * 2 as 'six'
```

You need do something like this

```
SELECT subQuery.'three' * 2 as 'six'
FROM 
    (SELECT 1 + 2  as 'three') as subQuery
```

You create

```
ct.CWhereUsedName AS 'End Use',
```

And try to use `'End Use'` in a CASE at the same level

So replace

```
  CASE WHEN 'End Use'
  --with
  CASE WHEN t.CWhereUsedName
```